# Nonlinear Recursion Solution Process for $x_{n+1}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}x_{n-i}$ (Known Solution)

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system

I want to solve the equation $x_{n+1}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}x_{n-i}$. Plugging the equation into Mathematica gives me $x_n=(-1)^{n}2^{2n+1} Binomial(1/2, n+1)x_0^{n+1}$. How might I derive this?

Comment: With [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)?

Comment: @Somos I'm not entirely sure how to use generating functions, but thank you, I will see if I can read about them and understand how to use them.

Comment: See [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) first proof for an example.

Comment: @Somos Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for, and it really helps me learn the process so I can try extending it to other situations. Thanks so much!